# Time comlexity of nested loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for( ; i < n; i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

What is the time complexity of this code? 
The outer loop runs n times but I'm not sure about inner loop. If the inner loop runs up til n for each value of i, can it be O(n^2) ?

Comment: Hint: `i` is incremented in the inner loop as well, so the outer loop will only run one time.

Comment: Okay! Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time complexity is O(n), because you're using the same variable inside the inner loop.

---

> The outer loop runs n times

No, this is incorrect. The inner loop will start on the first iteration with `i = 0`, then it will iterate till `i = n`, and then the outer loop will check `i < n` (i.e. `n < n === false`) and then exit.

Comment: Understood! Thank you!